# Code is pretending like a variable doesn't exist

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically, I need to do a one time check of what the length of an audio clip is and then store it in a variable to use as the length of time the code should wait before proceeding and destroying the game object.

I've tried numerous different things like taking it outside of the if statement and such but, every attempt has lead this code to either work but, not as intended or just refuse to compile.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

 public class Fighting : MonoBehaviour
{

public int Team = 1; //Which team entity is on
public int Health = 100; //How much heath it has
public int MaxHealth = 100; //Maximum health cap
public int AttackDamage = 10; //Attack Damage to enemy entities
public int HealAmount = 0; //Amount it can heal friendly entities
public int DecayAmount = 1; //Amount of health lost over time (If over health cap)
public float DecayCooling = 1; //Seconds it takes for health to be lost over time (If over health cap)
public float DecayOriginal = 1; //Needs to be hidden and equal to DecayCooling
public float CoolDown = 2; //Seconds it takes until it can attack enemies again
public float original = 2; //Needs to be hidden and equal to CoolDown
public bool CoolingDown = false; //Is attack cooling Down?
public bool Decaying = false; //Is decaying cooling Down?
public bool Structure = false; //Is it a building?
public bool SelfHealing = false; //Can it heal itself?
public bool HealAll = false; //Can it heal every friendly unit in its radius?
public bool Garrisoning = false; //Can it garrison troops?
public bool Snap = false; //Do you wanna snap it?
public bool clipplayed = false;
public bool lengthset = false;
public AudioSource aSource;
//public AudioSource[] mSource;
public Component[] obj;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Snap == true || Health <= 0) //Snaps the entity if either is true
    {
        //Destroy(gameObject, .5f);
        obj = transform.parent.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>();
        foreach (MeshRenderer rend in obj)
        {
            rend.enabled = false;
        }

        if (clipplayed == false)
        {
            aSource.Play();
            clipplayed = true;
        }

        bool playing = true;

        if (playing == false)
        {
            Destroy(transform.parent.gameObject);
        }

        if (playing == true)
        {
            if (lengthset == false)
            {
                float playtimer = aSource.clip.length;
                lengthset = true;
            }

            playtimer -= Time.deltaTime;

            if (playtimer <= 0)
            {
                playing = false;
            }

        }
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.N)) Instantiate(transform.parent.gameObject); //Debug tool to spawn another

    if (Health > MaxHealth && Decaying == false) //Checks to see if health should be decaying
    {
        Health -= DecayAmount;
        Decaying = true;
    }
    if (Decaying == true)
    {
        DecayCooling -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (DecayCooling <= 0)
        {
            Decaying = false;
            DecayCooling = DecayOriginal;
        }
    }
}

}
```

**These lines of code:**

playtimer -= Time.deltaTime;

if (playtimer <= 0)

**Should be able to see:**

float playtimer = aSource.clip.length;

Instead, they pretend as if it doesn't even exist and the script won't compile because of it.

Comment: What if lengthset == true? The type of playtimer isn't declared.

Comment: So how should I go about fixing the issue while retaining the intended functionality?

Comment: I built the code this way so that it would only execute once and not just keep setting the variable back to what it was over and over again. Is there a better way of accomplishing my intent?

Comment: if (playing == false) will never be called. you are declaring the variable  bool playing = true; above it

Comment: @Toxic Do you mean that the variable playtimer should be the same between calls to Update()?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! I managed to fix the issue and get the script working as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring playtimer within your if scope, so it doesn't exist when you call
    playtimer -= Time.deltaTime;

Look at it this way, what happens when lengthset is not false, you wouldn't have declared playtimer yet:

```
if (lengthset == false)
{
    float playtimer = aSource.clip.length;
    lengthset = true;
}
playtimer -= Time.deltaTime;
```

Instead, declare it outside of the if scope:

```
float playtimer = 0;
if (lengthset == false)
{
    playtimer = aSource.clip.length;
    lengthset = true;
}
playtimer -= Time.deltaTime;
```

Oh gosh, from your comment: "I built the code this way so that it would only execute once and not just keep setting the variable back to what it was over and over again. Is there a better way of accomplishing my intent?".

If  you need to track the value of playtimer between calls, then you probably want to add it as an instance variable (i.e., up top with all the other variables). Make sure to remove the declaration from the method logic if you do.

Answer (score 1):

Define `playtimer` variable one level higher to see it at both places.

```
float playtimer = 0;
if (lengthset == false)
{
    playtimer = aSource.clip.length;
    lengthset = true;
}

playtimer -= Time.deltaTime;
```

Comment: While the code with these adjustments, it does not work as intended. For some reason playing is never set to false and therefore the code just loops infinitely.

Comment: @Toxic `playing` only exists in your `Update()` method, so it will be initialized as `true` each time your method is called. That's outside the scope of this question, however.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, code in a nested scope can see variables defined outside the scope. Code outside the scope can't see variables defined inside the scope.

Therefore, the following won't work:

```
{
    int a = 5;
}

Console.WriteLine(a); // can't see a because it's declaration is in the nested scope
```

but this will work:

```
int a = 0;

{
    a = 5;
}

Console.WriteLine(a); // can see a, its value is 5
```

In this example, a is declared outside the two nested scopes, so it can be accessed by both of them:

```
{
    int a = 5;

    {
        a = 3;
    }

    {
        Console.WriteLine(a); // this will also work because a is declared outside the scope. Its value is 3.
    }
}
```

If you need `playTimer` to be the same variable (i.e. contain the same value) between calls to `Update()`, you need to move its declaration outside the scope of `Update()` and into the scope of the class-level scope.

For example:

```
class Test
{
    float playTimer = 0;

    void Update()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(playTimer);
    }
}
```